# Órgão ou entidade que estabelece padrões para o desenvolvimento web

Tags: convenções-de-nome

Por vezes, o consenso entre projetistas e desenvolvedores web referente à padrões nos "força", quase que exclusivamente, a utilizar [padrões de fato](http://www.batebyte.pr.gov.br/modules/conteudo/conteudo.php?conteudo=708). Gostaria de saber se existe algum órgão ou entidade que estabelece [padrões de direito](http://www.batebyte.pr.gov.br/modules/conteudo/conteudo.php?conteudo=708) para o desenvolvimento web, tais como nomenclatura, indentação, etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, existe o [**W3C**](https://www.w3.org) (não confundir com w3schools pelo amor de deus). É ele quem define os padrões do HTML e do CSS. No caso da linguagem JavaScript, quem define os padrões é um comitê ligado à [ECMA](https://www.ecma-international.org), uma associação internacional parecida com a [ISO](https://www.iso.org/home.html). Em ambos os casos, as decisões são tomadas por comitês que envolvem especialistas da área, incluindo representantes dos fabricantes de browsers.

Porém, eles definem basicamente padrões de sintaxe, definindo o que pode ser usado em determinada tecnologia ou não. Não é o caso de coisas como nomenclatura e indentação, que não são padronizados oficialmente nas linguagens citadas¹, ficando a decisão final a cargo dos próprios desenvolvedores.

¹ Em linguagens como Python a indentação faz parte da própria sintaxe, e nesse caso é definida no standard.

Comment: *não confundir com w3schools* +1