# Selecionar apenas últimas mensagens Chat MySql

Tags: php, android, mysql

Estou criando um bate papo num aplicativo android e preciso exibir essa tela:
[image: Tela APP]
Meu banco de dados está assim:
Tabela mensagens:

[image: BancoDados mensagens]

Estou fazendo um essa consulta exemplo para o usuario que tem id=43

```
SELECT m.dono, m.dest , m.recebido, m.data, 
IF(m.dono=43,(SELECT nick FROM usuarios WHERE id=m.dest),(SELECT nick FROM usuarios WHERE id=m.dono)) AS nick,
IF(m.dono=43,(SELECT foto FROM usuarios WHERE id=m.dest),(SELECT foto FROM usuarios WHERE id=m.dono)) AS foto
FROM mensagens as m
WHERE (m.dono = 43 or m.dest=43) 
ORDER BY  m.data desc
```

e então no PHP eu filtro os resultados e mando os dados pro app o problema que essa consulta esta pegando todos os chats do usuario! imagine quando estiver com 1 ano de chat a quantidade de mensagens que vai processar para mostrar apenas isso...
já tentei usar Group by m.dono+m.dest ai ele retorna dados faltando :\

Eu preciso apenas da ultima mensagem enviada ou recebida para os outros
estou recebendo isso:

```
manda - recebe - data - nick - foto
43 29 0 2017-08-24 20:15:53  rafael sp Sm9zw6kg.jpg
43 29 0 2017-08-24 20:08:53  rafael sp   Sm9zw6kg.jpg
43 23 0 2017-08-24 20:05:53  Jose fsdfsdfs.jpg
29 43 0 2017-08-23 10:15:53  rafael sp Sm9zw6kg.jpg
```

e não apenas

```
43 29 0 2017-08-24 20:15:53  rafael sp Sm9zw6kg.jpg
43 23 0 2017-08-24 20:05:53  Jose fsdfsdfs.jpg
```

Comment: simplesmente LIMIT 50 por exemplo.

Comment: @ViniciusPuttiMorais mas se eu usar um LIMIT ele vai limitar os resultados considerando as mais recentes, se por exemplo eu o usuario 43 trocar 52 mensagens com o usuario 20, e antes disso falou com o usuario 30...
minha consulta vai retornar apenas as conversar com usuario 20... quando eu filtrar os resultados apenas ele vai aparece :\

Comment: tu especifica WHERE usuario = 20, dai ele vai pegar as primerias mensagens trocadas com o ususario 20.

Comment: Mas não é isso que preciso, eu preciso da ultima mensagem trocada com qualquer usuário... independente  se eu mandei a mensam ou recebi, assim como é na pagina principal dos chats no whatsapp por exemplo

Answer (score 1):

Consegui! e ainda estou mandando as não lidas rsrsrsr obrigado a todos pelas respostas!

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT m.data,
IF(m.dono=43, 0 ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mensagens WHERE (dono=m.dono and dest=43 and recebido=0))) AS naolido,
IF(m.dono=43, 1 ,m.recebido ) AS recebido,
IF(m.dono=43, m.dest , m.dono) AS id,
IF(m.dono=43,(SELECT nick FROM usuarios WHERE id=m.dest),(SELECT nick FROM usuarios WHERE id=m.dono)) AS nick,
IF(m.dono=43,(SELECT foto FROM usuarios WHERE id=m.dest),(SELECT foto FROM usuarios WHERE id=m.dono)) AS foto
FROM mensagens as m
WHERE (m.dono = 43 or m.dest=43)
ORDER BY  m.id desc) as temp
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY data desc
```

Comment: Rapaz, apesar de você ter encontrado uma solução para seu problema, não faça isso. Utilize `JOIN`. Esses `IF´, `SELECT` internos, vários `GROUP BY` e `ORDER BY`  vão crashar seriamente o teu sistema. Onde você mesmo disse "*1 ano de chat a quantidade de mensagens que vai processar*"

Comment: Ainda não consegui fazer uma busca melhor, essa esta respondendo rápido mas não tenho nem 1.000 registros no banco ainda

Answer (score 0):

Simplesmente inclua na sua query a palavra LIMIT, por exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM nome_da_tabela LIMIT 30
```

Vai selecionar apenas os 30 primeiros registros. Pra pegar os outros registros voce pode fazer assim:

```
SELECT * FROM nome_da_tabela LIMIT 10 OFFSET 15
```

Vai selecionar os 10 primeiros registros a partir do 15, ou seja, do 16 ao 25.

Comment: Sim mas não existe uma forma de filtrar os dados no banco de dados? eu realmente não estou achando legal ficar fazendo tantos select e verificando todos os resultados no php... estou quase certo que tem como fazer só não sei como... no seu exemplo meu problema continua a diferença que não teria problema com estouro de memoria mas faria vários select

Answer (score 0):

Use o limit do MySQl, abaixo a referencia do W3C para te ajudar:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

Exemplo:

```
SELECT m.dono, 
       m.dest, 
       m.recebido, 
       m.data, 
       IF(m.dono=43,
         (SELECT nick FROM usuarios WHERE id=m.dest),
         (SELECT nick FROM usuarios WHERE id=m.dono)) AS nick,
       IF(m.dono=43,
         (SELECT foto FROM usuarios WHERE id=m.dest),
         (SELECT foto FROM usuarios WHERE id=m.dono)) AS foto
  FROM mensagens as m
 WHERE (m.dono = 43 or m.dest=43) 
 ORDER BY  m.data desc LIMIT 10
```

Porem, fazendo da forma exemplificada acima, você teria um problema com o seu order by, o limit ele restringe 10 registros independente da ordenação, e depois ele aplicaria o order by pela data, não trazendo o cenário real das últimas mensagens, precisaria fazer conforme a query abaixo:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT m.dono, 
           m.dest, 
           m.recebido, 
           m.data, 
           IF(m.dono=43,
             (SELECT nick FROM usuarios WHERE id=m.dest),
             (SELECT nick FROM usuarios WHERE id=m.dono)) AS nick,
           IF(m.dono=43,
             (SELECT foto FROM usuarios WHERE id=m.dest),
             (SELECT foto FROM usuarios WHERE id=m.dono)) AS foto
      FROM mensagens as m
     WHERE (m.dono = 43 or m.dest=43) 
     ORDER BY  m.data desc) LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Ainda assim não funcionaria, se o usuário de 43 trocar mais de 10 mensagens com o usuario 20 e antes disso ele conversou com o usuario 30 apenas o chat com o usuario 20 aparece

Comment: entendi, então você precisa das ultimas 10 mensagens de todos os usuários que aquele usuário trocou mensagem?

Comment: Apenas a ultima pra exibir essa tela, ultima mensagem envia ou recebida que tem para cada usuario

Comment: Sobre [W3C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/218813/%C3%93rg%C3%A3o-ou-entidade-que-estabelece-padr%C3%B5es-para-o-desenvolvimento-web/218816#comment447894_218816)